# Responsive Column to Row depending on content size

Tags: flutter

I want to build a responsive widget in flutter that aligns buttons (mostly two) in the same row, if they fit and if not they should be placed in separate rows. We want a behavior where they fill the full width of the parent, when in "column mode" and in "row mode" they should fill each half of the available space. We would use it like this:

```
CustomResponsiveWrap(
  children: [
    Button('Ok'),
    Button('not Ok')],
  spacing: 10);
```

Here are two pictures on how it should look like in column and row mode:
[Buttons are too big for one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itQH7.png)
[Buttons fit into one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU3rR.png)

At first I tried using Wrap, but that does not allow to fine-tune the behavior. I believe a normal MediaQuery would not work either. The text-content of the buttons is different in different languages and the actual size is quite "hard" to estimate (e.g. with OS-Zoom, special characters in other alphabets, etc.).

After that I tried using `CustomMultiChildLayout`. I think for the behavior that I want it is necessary to get the size of the buttons in the row-layout to determine if the row-mode is feasible and if not I have to "relayout" into column-mode. This is not possible in `CustomMultiChildLayout` as the `MultiChildLayoutDelegate` complains when you do a `layoutChild` on one child not exactly one time (and I could do it more than once with my method).

I now solved it by copying all the `CustomMultiChildLayout` code and removing the assertion that tests for multiple calls to `layoutChild` for one child and that works. Sadly subclassing did not work and I find the solution rather dissatisfying.

My question now is: Is there a flutter widget / render class that is better suited for the use case or is there some way of doing this with existing widgets that I do not know of / or know how? And lastly what implications do multiple layout calls to a child have other than decreased performance (we only have two, perhaps three buttons with text and a border so it should not be too bad performance wise for us).

### Update

For everyone who is interested in how I do it now. I've put the idea of it into this DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/9c9576f1840823cac44b2ce63fd200e3 . It creates a similar Widget to `CustomMultiChildLayout` that supports relayouting. I did keep the general structure of it. I liked the LayoutIDs instead of "fiddling around" with the next/previous child functions of the `ContainerRenderObjectMixin`.

Comment: What do you mean "Wrap does not allow to fine tune the behavior"?

Comment: When using Wrap it does use a second row, when the items do not fit, but it does not force every single child to then fill the full width, when it needs more than two lines.

Comment: From https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html :

`[...] but the size of the parent cannot depend on the sizes of the children.`

So you probably shouldn't use this widget in that use-case.
Afaik a [RenderBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html) could help you out here, as it can get the size of its children to size itself.
Although this seems like a very low-level method of doing so.

Comment: @LinuCC Ah I did not see that sentence. So my "self-made" solution now uses RenderBox, seems like that is the only way of doing this. Thank you :)